# Titan With Cassandra as Backend : creating , storing and traversing the graph in java

Tags: java, cassandra, graph-databases, titan, graph-traversal

I am dead new to Titan and when I started researching on it I have got confused as it has plethora of new things under the hood like Gremlin , tinkerpop and rexter etc.

What I want is an example in java which makes use of titan with Cassandra as a back end. I would like to create a graph , store in cassandra , retrieve it back and traverse it. A very simple would also be a lot helpful.

I got a basic example in java that I ran.

```
    BaseConfiguration baseConfiguration = new BaseConfiguration();
    baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra");
    baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.hostname", "192.168.3.82");

    TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(baseConfiguration);

     Vertex rash = titanGraph.addVertex(null);
        rash.setProperty("userId", 1);
        rash.setProperty("username", "rash");
        rash.setProperty("firstName", "Rahul");
        rash.setProperty("lastName", "Chaudhary");
        rash.setProperty("birthday", 101);

        Vertex honey = titanGraph.addVertex(null);
        honey.setProperty("userId", 2);
        honey.setProperty("username", "honey");
        honey.setProperty("firstName", "Honey");
        honey.setProperty("lastName", "Anant");
        honey.setProperty("birthday", 201);

        Edge frnd = titanGraph.addEdge(null, rash, honey, "FRIEND");
        frnd.setProperty("since", 2011);

        titanGraph.shutdown();
```

So when I run this , I observed the cassandra logs and it created a keyspace named titan and the following tables :

- titan_ids
- edgestore
- graphindex
- system_properties
- systemlog
- txlog
- edgestore_lock_
- graphindex_lock_
- system_properties_lock_

I don't know what these tables are used for and how are they storing the data.

After running the program , which creates a graph of 2 vertex's and a edge between them.  I queried the tables and found some hexadecimal values in each of the table.

I have the following questions :

1. How is the graph being stored in cassandra ?
2. Now that I have this graph say 'x' stored in cassandra . Say I created another graph 'y' and store it. How will be able to retrieve and traverse any particular graph ? Because in a normal cql query you know the table and the column's to query . How will I Identify 'x' and 'y' separately.
3. Could any one help posting an example code in java to create a graph using some sample csv data. Store in Cassandra and some traversal examples of the same graph . Will be a lot helpful as there no such example available which is understandable.

Comment: Do you really need Titan? Datastax has graphs on Cassandra. http://www.datastax.com/dse-graph-campaign/index.html

Comment: @cricket_007 DSE is a commercial product only I believe. So using titan is a good alternative choice if you can't spare the money for DSE. [JanusGraph](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph) is also a good free alternative.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I signed up for a free account and have installed DSE before

Comment: @cricket_007 will take another look at it, thanks. I was under the impression that to deploy DSE Graph in large scale production you had to pay for it.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I'll clarify. For "non-production purposes," you can use it for free. http://www.datastax.com/enterprise-terms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few questions in there so I will try to answer as much as I can.

**Question 1:**

If you interested in how the data is persisted into the DB then you should take a look [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/data-model.html) it describes the titan data model in detail. I am not sure how well it translates to the commit logs and tables but it's a start.

**Question 2:**

So the reason you ended up with a keysoace called `titan` is because you did not provide your own. Usually when creating different graphs that have nothing to do with each other you would store those graphs in different keyspaces. This is done as follows:

```
BaseConfiguration baseConfiguration = new BaseConfiguration();
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra");
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.hostname", "192.168.3.82");

//First Graph
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.cassandra.keyspace", "keyspace1");
TitanGraph titanGraph1 = TitanFactory.open(baseConfiguration);

//Second Graph
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.cassandra.keyspace", "keyspace2");
TitanGraph titanGraph2 = TitanFactory.open(baseConfiguration);
```

Of course you can create multiple disconnected graphs in the same keysoace as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545537/1457059)

**Question 3:**

That is a bit of a loaded question asking for a sample CSV migration. I would say take a step back and ask yourself, what are you trying to model.

Lets say you want to store a list of products and a list of people who bought those products. There are a multitude of ways you could model this but for now lets just say that people and products are vertices and the edges between then represent a purchase:

```
//Initliase graph
BaseConfiguration baseConfiguration = new BaseConfiguration();
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.backend", "cassandra");
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.hostname", "192.168.3.82");
baseConfiguration.setProperty("storage.cassandra.keyspace", "mycustomerdata");
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(baseConfiguration);

//---------------- Adding Data -------------------
//Create some customers
Vertex alice = graph.addVertex("customer");
alice.property("name", "Alice Mc Alice");
alice.property("birthdat", "100000 BC");

Vertex bob = graph.addVertex("customer");
bob.property("name", "Bob Mc Bob");
bob.property("birthdat", "1000 BC");

//Create Some Products
Vertex meat = graph.addVertex("product");
meat.property("name", "Meat");
meat.property("description", "Delicious Meat");

Vertex lettuce = graph.addVertex("product");
lettuce.property("name", "Lettuce");
lettuce.property("description", "Delicious Lettuce which is green");

//Alice Bought some meat:
alice.addEdge("bought", meat);
//Bob Bought some meat and lettuce:
bob.addEdge("bought", meat, lettuce);

//---------------- Querying (aka traversing whcih is what you do in graph dbs) Data -------------------
//Now who has bought meat?
graph.traversal().V().has("name", "meat").in("bought").forEachRemaining(v -> System.out.println(v.value("name")));

//Who are all our customers
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("customer").forEachRemaining(v -> System.out.println(v.value("name")));

//What products do we have
graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("customer").forEachRemaining(v -> System.out.println(v.value("name")));
```

The above example is a simple use of Titan. I would reccomend running through the [tinkerpop] documentation so that you can familiarise yourself with using it. At the end of the day you interface with titan via the Tinkerpop API.

I hope this helps you somewhat